# Whether the Propagation delay contains the signal from chain into the cache queue?

Tags: networking

From the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_delay):

> Propagation delay – time for a signal to reach its destination

and from the [slideplayer.com](https://slideplayer.com/slide/8727034/) I found the image:

[image]

there seems the Propagation delay represent the signal transport on the chain and `into the other router`(whether this is mean  `signal into the cache queue` contained in the propagation delay), there do not make it clear the whether the propagation delay contains the `signal into the cache queue`.

So, I want to make it clear in this professional networking site.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The propagation delay does not include processing overhead like queueing/unqueueing. It's purely medium-in to medium-out. Neither egress nor ingress queueing, nor serialization ("transmission delay" in your diagram) is part of the propagation delay.

Comment: but how about the duration of `signal into the cache queue`? it belongs to which delay?

Comment: The send queue is no cache, and no, that's processing overhead and it doesn't count as propagation.